# Create spectogram from multiple fft's in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I've have a few FFT's which I want to bring into the form of an "spectogram".
I want to see the different fft's as line in the X axis (time) and the frequency in the Y axis. The values should be visualised in a colour bar like this:

[image]

I use Python and the scipy for the spectogram.

Before I visualise all the FFT's I tried to do it with a single one like this:

```
    from scipy.signal import spectrogram
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...
    f, t1, Sxx = spectrogram(data, 2048)
    plt.pcolormesh(t1, f, Sxx)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

At least. This will not throw an exception and shows a plot which is not as i expected. I tried some things but I don't get it.

The data is a list of 2048 floats. sometimes 4096. Depends on the measuring. In this case 2048. The plot looks like this:

[image]

I expected a single horizontal line with de frequency in the x axis and the Values colour coded.

Comment: What is the data? What is the plot that is produced? How is it not as expected? How do you expect anyone to help you while providing no information whatsoever?

Comment: The data is a list of 2048 floats. sometimes 4096. Depends on the measuring. In this case 2048. The plot looks like this: https://www.img-load.de/image/MX02Si and i expected a single horizontal line with de frequency in the x axis and the Values colour coded.

Comment: Consider using stack overflow's image upload feature

Comment: step one is to get working a single fft which should generate a single line where x axis would be your frequency and y does not change then on that line color represents the magnitude of a given freq bin ... once you have this working then iterate across each of your time periods and repeat creation of this line where each line increments y

Comment: I think the issue here is understanding what spectrogram() actually does and what an FFT is, which would be better answered on signal processing SE

Comment: If you have 2048 data points, it doesn't make any sense to compute a spectrogram w/ the fft length = 2048.  Try 128.  Then try plotting log10(Sxx)

Comment: There are multiple stripes along the time axis because `spectrogram` by default takes 256 input samples at a time, zero pads it to your requested 2048 fft length, computes the fft for that strip then shifts over by 224 samples then keeps repeating untill the 2048 samples are processed (producing 9x1025 values). `pcolormesh` throws out the last row&column, so you get an 8x1024 figure. You could try playing with `spectrogram`'s `nperseg` and `noverlap` parameters to get what you are looking for.